# Excel compare partial cell contents

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I am currently comparing two lists of email address to find matches between the two.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Sheet1!Z:Z, 0)), "No Match", "Match")
```

My problem is that some emails I want to INCLUDE are for example :

```
John.Smith@Email.com
John.Smith-Work@Email.com
```

How can I do my match lookup to allow for this variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you should be able to make it work.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!Z:Z,LEFT(C2,FIND(C2,"@"))&"*"&RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(C2,"@")))<1, "No Match", "Match")
```

Try `=LEFT(C2,FIND(C2,"@"))&"*"&RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(C2,"@"))` first,
to see if you have `John.Smith*@Email.com` or if you need to add a `-1` or `+1` somewhere!

Comment: R3uK, when running =LEFT(C2,FIND(C2,"@"))&"*"&RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(C2,"@")) I get a #VALUE

Comment: @user2110655 : Did you try to evaluate the formula step by step to see where is the problem coming from? Is C2 an email?

Comment: @user2110655 : Go to the Formula tab, Formula checking part, and click on Evaluate formula, there you can have a step by step that should be able to narrow down the issue! ;)

Answer (score 1):

R3uK, close, stepping through your statement I found the following to work for me.

First Check:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(G2,FIND("-",G2)-1)&RIGHT(G2,LEN(G2)-FIND("@",G2)+1), "")
```

Final Function

```
=IF(COUNTIF(TERMINATIONS!AA:AA,LEFT(G2,FIND("-",G2)-1)&RIGHT(G2,LEN(G2)-FIND("@",G2)+1))<1, "No Match", "Match")
```

Comment: Ok, I thought you were trying the other way around, because if you look closely in my proposition, you'll see a `*` which is a wildcard, so using it in the countif will allow it to match both part `John.Smith` and `@Email.com` with anything in the middle, so it'll be wider than the solution you went with (but maybe not easily usable in the direction that you use). Any, glad I could. Please accept my answer to close this question